# Is it possible to subscribe to an action feedback?

Tags: ros, ros2, action, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was considering to is it possible to subscribe to a action feedback from another node. I tried it to subscribe a moveit2 action feedback ( **/scaled_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/_action/feedback**) from a node.

Before run the node:

```
ros2 topic info /scaled_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/_action/feedback
Type: control_msgs/action/FollowJointTrajectory_FeedbackMessage
Publisher count: 1
Subscription count: 2
```

After run the node

```
ros2 topic info /scaled_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/_action/feedback
Type: [‘control_msgs/action/FollowJointTrajectory_Feedback’, ‘control_msgs/action/FollowJointTrajectory_FeedbackMessage’]
Publisher count: 1
Subscription count: 3
```

But when action feedback starts to come , in node callback function is not triggering. And also when i check the node info

```
ros2 node info /anlys_node 
/anlys_node
Subscribers:

Publishers:
/parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
/rosout: rcl_interfaces/msg/Log
Service Servers:
/anlys_node/describe_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/DescribeParameters
/anlys_node/get_parameter_types: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameterTypes
/anlys_node/get_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameters
/anlys_node/list_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/ListParameters
/anlys_node/set_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters
/anlys_node/set_parameters_atomically: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParametersAtomically
Service Clients:

Action Servers:

Action Clients:
/scaled_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory: control_msgs/action/FollowJointTrajectory_Feedback
```

As seen above , its created Action Clients not Subscribers.

I didn’t get what is up going here, am i doing something wrong or is there a bug ?

Here is my node script.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3

 import rclpy
 from rclpy.node import Node

 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import yaml

from control_msgs.action import FollowJointTrajectory

class PlanAnlys(Node):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__('anlys_node')

    self.get_logger().info("Node Init")

    self.create_subscription(FollowJointTrajectory.Feedback,"/scaled_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory/_action/feedback",self.save_data,10)

    
    



def save_data(self,msg):
    
    self.get_logger().info("Test")




rclpy.init()

node = PlanAnlys()

rclpy.spin(node)


node.destroy_node()
rclpy.shutdown()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404815/is-it-possible-to-subscribe-to-an-action-feedback?/) by [muratcngncr](https://answers.ros.org/users/113382/muratcngncr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2022-08-09

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2022-08-09**:
did you do a ros2 topic echo to make sure data is on the topic ?, also be careful with QOS compatibility of publisher and subscriber,

**Comment by [muratcngncr](https://answers.ros.org/users/113382/muratcngncr/) on 2022-08-10**:
Yeah when i send a goal to action server. I can see the feedback topic via ros2 topic  echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The key is in the type. If you show the topic (`ros2 topic list --include-hidden-topics -t`) you'll probably see that the type of the feedback is not "FollowJointTrajectory.Feedback" but `FollowJointTrajectory_FeedbackMessage`.

That type is hidden as well, but you should be able to import it as follows:

`from control_msgs.action._follow_joint_trajectory import FollowJointTrajectory_FeedbackMessage`

This worked for me in Humble

---

Originally posted by [iwasinnam](https://answers.ros.org/users/135060/iwasinnam/) with karma: 46 on 2023-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3